# Combining Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda

I have this method

```
public Expression<Func<Auction, bool>> GetUnsetDatesAuctionsExpression()
        {
            if (condition)
                return GetAllUnsetDatesAuctionsExpression();
            else
                return (a =>
                        (membershipUser.ProviderUserKey != null) &&
                        (a.OwnerReference == (Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey) &&
                        ((a.Starts == null) || (a.Ends == null)));
            }
        }
```

which calls this method

```
private Expression<Func<Auction, bool>> GetAllUnsetDatesAuctionsExpression()
        {
            return (a => (a.Starts == null) || (a.Ends == null));
        }
```

The issue is that in the above public method I have the below line

```
(a.Starts == null) || (a.Ends == null)
```

which is the same as the body of the expression in the private method.

Now, doing this, of course, does not work because you can't AND a bool and an Expression

```
return (a =>
   (membershipUser.ProviderUserKey != null) &&
   (a.OwnerReference == (Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey) &&
   (GetAllUnsetDatesAuctionsExpression));
```

So, the question is, how do I combine the call to the private method with

```
(membershipUser.ProviderUserKey != null) &&
   (a.OwnerReference == (Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey)
```

Comment: Have you tried (GetAllUnsetDatesAuctionsExpression)(a) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new expression as a combination of the two, see [BinaryExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression.aspx):

```
System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression binaryExpression =
  System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeBinary(
    System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.AndAlso,
    firstExpression,
    secondExpression);
```

Comment: problem is that my public method GetUnsetDatesAuctionsExpression returns an Expression not a BinaryExpresssion.

Comment: @Sachin - A BinaryExpression is still an Expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (I removed superfluous parentheses):

```
return a =>
    membershipUser.ProviderUserKey != null &&
    a.OwnerReference == (Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey &&
    GetAllUnsetDatesAuctionsExpression().Compile()(a);
    // ---------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The code above uses [Expression.Compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx) method to compile the lambda expression described by the expression tree (returned by your `GetAllUnsetDatesAuctionsExpression()` method) into executable code and produce a delegate that represents the lambda expression.

**Edit:** I didn't notice that your public method returned an expression, not a value. In your scenario [Hans Kesting's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9210623/93462) is much better, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not change it the this expression:

```
return (a => (a.Starts == null || a.Ends == null));
```